# Parse.com Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {oauth=www-authenticate: OAuth realm="https://api.twitter.com"}

Tags: android, authentication, twitter, parse-platform

After upgrading Parse Android SDK to version 1.4.1 Twitter login stopped to work. When I'm trying to login with Twitter:

```
ParseTwitterUtils.initialize(Constants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
ParseTwitterUtils.logIn(activity, new LogInCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            // Success
        } else {
            // Error
        }
    }
});
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {oauth=www-authenticate: OAuth realm="https://api.twitter.com"}
```

I've already asked a question on [Parse.com](https://www.parse.com/questions/authentication-error-unable-to-respond-to-any-of-these-challenges-oauthwww-authenticate-oauth-realmhttpsapitwittercom) but maybe you guys know what is the problem. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Resolved this problem by specifying `http://www.localhost.com/callback` for Callback URL and `http://www.localhost.com` for a website in the Twitter application settings.

Answer (score 0):

As the other members suggested, you need to specify the Callback URL and Website in the Twitter app, also pay attention on how you initialise the ParseTwitterUtils.

Just for testing purposes please try to use the consumer key and secret directly, just to see if it works, something like:

```
...
ParseTwitterUtils.initialize("TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY", "TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET");
ParseTwitterUtils.logIn(this, new LogInCallback() {
...
```

*** Note: This is not a best practice !!!